# Shopify Python API: How do I add a product to a collection?

Tags: python, django, api, shopify

I am using the Shopify Python API in an django app to interact with my Shopify Store.

I have a collection - called - best sellers.

I am looking to create a batch update to this collection - that is add/remove products to this collection. However, they python API docs does not seem to say much about how to do so. How do I fetch a collection by name? How do I add a product to it?

Thank you for your help.

---

This is what I found

> > > x=shopify.CustomCollection.find(handle="best-sellers")
> > >
> > > y=shopify.Collect() #creates a new collect
> > >
> > > p = shopify.Product.find(118751076) # gets me the product

So the questions is how do I add the product "p" above to the Custom Collection "x" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a collect to add a product to a custom collection.

[Shopify API – Collect Documentation](http://api.shopify.com/collect.html#create)

This can be done using the Shopify Python API as follows

```
collect = shopify.Collect({ 'product_id': product_id, 'collection_id': collection_id })
collect.save()
```

Comment: Also, I figured this works too - which is the same as what you posted:>>> z=shopify.Collect()
>>> z.product_id = p.id
>>> z.collection_id = x[0].id
>>> z.save()

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is again not promising but one thing to bear in mind is that there should in actual fact be an existing collection already created

Find it by using this code

`collection_id = shopify.CustomCollection.find(handle=<your_handle>)[0].id`

then consequently add the collection_id, product_id to a Collect object and save, remember to first save your product (or have an existing one which you can find) and then only save your collection, or else the collection won't know what product its posting to (via the api), like so

`new_product = shopify.Product()`

`new_product.save()`

`add_collection = shopify.Collect('product_id': new_product.id, 'collection_id': collection_id})`

`add_collection.save()`

Also important to note that there is a 1 to 1 relationship between Product and Collect

Answer (score -1):

Fetches all products that belong to a certain collection

```
>>> shopify.Product.find(collection_id=841564295)
[product(632910392)]
```

Create a new product with multiple product variants

```
>>> new_product = shopify.Product()
>>> print new_product.id  # Only exists in memory for now
None
>>> new_product.product_type = "Snowboard"
>>> new_product.body_html = "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>"
>>> new_product.title = "Burton Custom Freestlye 151"
>>> variant1 = shopify.Variant()
>>> variant2 = shopify.Variant(dict(price="20.00", option1="Second")) # attributes can     be set at creation
>>> new_product.variants = [variant1, variant2]
>>> new_product.vendor = "Burton"
>>> new_product.save()  # Sends request to Shopify
True
>>> new_product.id
1048875193
```

via - http://wiki.shopify.com/Using_the_shopify_python_api#Receive_a_list_of_all_Products

Comment: Where in the above is the code to map the product to the collection?